# Expo app ios build crashes instantly after splash screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, eas

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

export default function App() {
  function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  function SettingsScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I used eas build and eas submit to submit the simple app described in the code to the app store to test it using testflight. As soon as I open the app it crashes. I think it has to do with the react native navigation library (?). How do I run the app wuthout any crashes?